# how to use TeamViewer to start multiple DIFFERENT sessions on the same SUSE linux machine?

Tags: linux, kde, teamviewer, suse

We have a system running on SLES (Suse Linux Enterprise Server) and I am looking to allow remote users to access the system using TeamViewer where each user starts a new KDE session when they log in.

Normally when TeamViewer is started within a KDE session then all users are in the same session and see the same screen however we need each user to be able to work independently in their own session.